# cloud functions: trying to create user on firestore from cloud functions "failed to deploy"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access my db upon http request.

in the api builder from google i use node.js 16 as a runtime.

I tried running this code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firestore);

const firestoreDB = admin.firestore()


exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase Cloud Functions!");
  console.log("function triggered")
});

exports.createUser = functions.firestore.document('Users/asddsa')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newValue = snap.data();
    if (snap.data() === null) return null;
    const uid = context.params.userId
    let notificationCollectionRef = firestoreDB.collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('Notifications')
    return notificationCollectionRef.add({
      notification: 'Hello Notification',
      notificationType: 'Welcome'
    }).then(ref => {
      return console.log('notification successful', ref.id)
    })
  });
```

But I cant even deploy it, it just states that "deployment failed".

Now this is usually when there is a typo in the code. But I am guessing that I didnt set up the connection to the firestore properley. (I never gave it a password or anything)

I assumed that as it is inside the same project, the connection would work either way, but maybe I am wrong?

How do I set up the connection to create the user and not have the deployment fail?

Comment: I have posted the answer. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for Initial setup to configure and set up your Cloud Functions for Firebase project. you can check the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

You can check the details in [Cloud firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created). Which describes Event triggers where you can trigger a function to fire any time a new document is created in a collection by using an onCreate(). This function calls createUser every time a new user profile is added.

Also You can have a look at [Github link](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/f1c45055b91672f27c094a77103c78f4) to create the user.